# Assigning List with preserving reference

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Suppose I have two `List`s and I want to copy/assign all of one list to another list with *preserving* reference to the original list. I use this code

```
List<String> mylist = new List<String>();
List<String> another = getSomeList();

// I have to do
mylist.clear();
mylist.addAll(another);
```

This works fine, but my question is, is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Collections.copy(dest, src), you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29

Comment: Let say for e.g. List1 = [1,2,3] and List2 = [4,5,6] so according to you what is the expected output ?

Comment: @sol4me `mylist=[4,5,6]` but with its own reference

Comment: then i think you can extract the fragment(which you already posted) into a method and put this method in some utility class

Comment: @abforce NO, there's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easier way. You can just implement your own list that has e.g. a `setAll()` method.

```
class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

  public void setAll(Collection<E> collection) {
    clear();
    addAll(collection);
  }

}
```

But this only moves the the `clear()` and `addAll()` invokation into another method. Sure from a clients prespective it makes the call easier

```
MyArrayList<String> mylist = new MyArrayList<String>();
mylist.setAll(another);
```

but at the price that you use a special list implementation. Maybe you only use this implementation inside of a class and your api does not expose that you use a `MyArrayList`. Than it might be ok. I would just do it the way you already do.

Comment: I'm sincerely grateful for your answer

Answer (score 0):

> is there any better way to do this?

No, not for your specifications. You can delete <strike>`mylist = another;`</strike>.

And there's no need to call `mylist.clear()` when you just assigned `mylist = new List<String>();`

So really all you need is that last line where you `addAll(another)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through first and add all elements into another:

```
for(String s : mylist){
  another.add(s);
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong in my ans? You want to copy all elements from first list into another without loosing reference to first. In this way you copy all the references from first list, not the list reference by itself.

Comment: I need a method to empty `mylist` and then fill it with items in `another`

Comment: And for doing this, you don't think you will need a temp list to store all the elements before you can clean the list? Because otherwise, if you clean the list first, then it doesn't have any references. And, in the future, be more explicit with your intends before downvoting.